# I'm trying to change the "value" on each item from an array but every time this error happen "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the values on the created elements and to make the work simpler I gave classes to them so could easily change their content later as an array but when I try doesn't work at all

```js
    let div_section = document.createElement('div');
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let section_boxes = document.createElement('section');
        section_boxes +1;
        section_boxes.setAttribute('class','box');
        div_section.appendChild(section_boxes);
    
        let boxes_h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        boxes_h2 +1;
        boxes_h2.setAttribute('class','boxesTitle');
        section_boxes.appendChild(boxes_h2);

        let boxes_p = document.createElement('p');
        boxes_p +1;
        boxes_p.setAttribute('class','boxesP');
        section_boxes.appendChild(boxes_p); 

        
    };

    //Grabing classes
    let getBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    let getTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('boxesTitle');
    let getText = document.getElementsByClassName('boxesP');
    

    //Don't know why doesn't work 
    getText[0].innerHTML = "Some Random text";
    getTitle[0].innerHTML = "Title";
    for(i = 0; i < getBoxes.length; i++){
        getBoxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#947062";
    };
```

Comment: its mean that ether `.boxesTitle` or `.boxesP` classes not found. check your html

Comment: I see the `.boxesTitle` and `.boxesP` appended to `section_boxes`, which you create dynamically. where you append `section_boxes` to the DOM?

Comment: You don't add `div_section`  to the document DOM

Comment: You forgot to add the `div_section` into the document and then you tried to select the elements from it. Add `document.body.appendChild(div_section)` after you populate the div. If you want to select without adding, then use `div_section.getElement...` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to append the body thats why

```
  let div_section = document.createElement("div");

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let section_boxes = document.createElement("section");
    section_boxes + 1;
    section_boxes.setAttribute("class", "box");
    div_section.appendChild(section_boxes);

    let boxes_h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    boxes_h2 + 1;
    boxes_h2.setAttribute("class", "boxesTitle");
    section_boxes.appendChild(boxes_h2);

    let boxes_p = document.createElement("p");
    boxes_p + 1;
    boxes_p.setAttribute("class", "boxesP");
    section_boxes.appendChild(boxes_p);
  }

  // addedline of code added
  document.body.append(div_section);

  //Grabing classes
  let getBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  let getTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("boxesTitle");
  let getText = document.getElementsByClassName("boxesP");

  //Don't know why doesn't work
  getText[0].innerHTML = "Some Random text";
  getTitle[0].innerHTML = "Title";
  for (i = 0; i < getBoxes.length; i++) {
    getBoxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#947062";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't add `div_section` to the document DOM.

```js
let div_section = document.createElement('div');

// This was missing
document.body.appendChild(div_section);

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let section_boxes = document.createElement('section');
    section_boxes +1;
    section_boxes.setAttribute('class','box');
    div_section.appendChild(section_boxes);

    let boxes_h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    boxes_h2 +1;
    boxes_h2.setAttribute('class','boxesTitle');
    section_boxes.appendChild(boxes_h2);

    let boxes_p = document.createElement('p');
    boxes_p +1;
    boxes_p.setAttribute('class','boxesP');
    section_boxes.appendChild(boxes_p); 

    
};

//Grabing classes
let getBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
let getTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('boxesTitle');
let getText = document.getElementsByClassName('boxesP');


getText[0].innerHTML = "Some Random text";
getTitle[0].innerHTML = "Title";
for(i = 0; i < getBoxes.length; i++){
    getBoxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#947062";
};
```